# Pandas moving average - drop negative values?

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

So in my dataframe, I have a column named diff that contains both positive and negative values.

```
date, id, diff, moving_avg
2017-01-01, 123, 5, 5
2017-01-02, 123, -3, 5
2017-01-03, 123, 4, (5+4)/2 = 4.5
2017-01-04, 123, 6, (4+6)/2 = 5
2017-01-05, 123, 3, (4+6+3)/3 = 4.33
```

I'm currently calculating the 3 day moving average as:

```
df['mov_avg_diff'] = df.groupby(['id'], as_index=False)[['diff']].rolling(
        3, min_periods=1).mean().fillna(0).reset_index(0, drop=True)
```

But this would include the negative values, thereby skewing the moving average. Is there a simple fix I can add to use only the positive values?

EDIT: added more rows/expected output

Comment: can't you just filter them out when you read your CSV ?

Comment: I suppose you'd need something like a `rolling.apply`, and pass a custom function that handles those negative values.

Comment: Can you provide some more data along with expected output please?

Comment: You could replace your negative values by the median of positive values for that app_id, and then do your rolling

Comment: @laguittemh the negatives aren't read in - the `diff` column is essentially the difference between values predicted by 2 different machine learning algorithms and is calculated on the fly

Comment: @Craig Shouldn't you be looking at the absolute differences then? Otherwise you are just throwing data away based on the direction of the difference.

Comment: @AlexZisman - We're trying to estimate the average difference when Model 1 underpredicts Model 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can replace the negative values with NaN using a boolean array like df[df > 0]. According to the docs, NaN will be correctly handled by pandas' methods: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html

Input (pandas_data.csv):

```
date,id,diff
2017-01-01,123,5
2017-01-02,123,-3
2017-01-03,123,4
2017-01-04,123,6
2017-01-05,123,3
2017-01-01,124,7
2017-01-02,124,1
2017-01-03,124,-4
2017-01-04,124,6
2017-01-05,124,2
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('pandas_data.csv', header=0)

df['mov_avg_diff'] = (
    df[df > 0]
    .groupby(['id'], as_index=False)['diff']
    .rolling(3, min_periods=1)
    .mean()
    .fillna(0)
    .reset_index(0, drop=True)).transpose()
```

Result:

```
df

         date   id  diff  mov_avg_diff
0  2017-01-01  123     5      5.000000
1  2017-01-02  123    -3      5.000000
2  2017-01-03  123     4      4.500000
3  2017-01-04  123     6      5.000000
4  2017-01-05  123     3      4.333333
5  2017-01-01  124     7      7.000000
6  2017-01-02  124     1      4.000000
7  2017-01-03  124    -4      4.000000
8  2017-01-04  124     6      3.500000
9  2017-01-05  124     2      4.000000
```

Comment: This isn't going to work sadly. The filtered df will be smaller in size, and you're attempting to assign it back to a larger column,

Comment: @Apollo2020 how would you incorporate the `groupby` here?

Comment: My answer yields the expected output according to your updated question. What are you trying to accomplish with the groupby()?

Comment: I've updated to use groupby() so that the moving average is applied to each id separately. I hope this is what you intended. If not, please let me know.

Comment: @Craig if this answer works for you would you please mark it as the correct answer? Thanks.